# For SQL like queries in MySQL and sqlite which more efficient for comparison text or int

Tags: performance, sqlite, processing-efficiency

I need to store 2 columns in SQLite db. a date (YYYY-MM-DD) and a time (HH-MM-SS)

Since SQLite can store date time in TEXT, REAL, INTEGER only which data type should I use ?
Is it more efficient to store as TEXT or INTEGER. I will be doing frequent lookup against these columns.
So my queries will have a WHERE condition on the date and time columns.

I want to make the WHERE comparison efficient

Answer (score 0):

The primary bottleneck when using databases is I/O.

If you care about performance, use the datatype which requires the least amount of I/O.
An INTEGER value needs less storage than a REAL one, which needs less than TEXT.

Whether this makes a noticeable difference is another question; you have to measure.